# Click on an edit button and delete button appear next to each item in the listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-alertdialog, android-button

I want to have a `Button` at the top of my `ListView` and when i click on it, a little delete Button should appear on each item in the `ListView`. And then an `AlertDialog` should appear when I press on the little delete button.

Could someone point me in the right direction on how to do this?
Please

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to follow the following steps:

- First of all make a layout consists of ListView with a button top of it.
- Make a custom row (with small delete button) which will be add in a
  ListView through CustomAdapter.
- Then Make a functionality of opening a dialog on click of a button.
- Finally Combine all above steps into one.

And you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create ListView with custom adapter.

Here is pretty good tutorial
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html